# Thread Exits Prematurely

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a Bodi server I'm running and it keeps exiting on a certain line as if the function is exiting ahead of schedule. I'd assume here (after trying Eclipse and NetBeans with same issue) that it's programmatical in nature the cause.  The parent thread polls checkinputqueue() and checkoutputqueue() and these in turn check if there is/are data for the server to flag as ready to be processed.

A Bodi server is a shared object server.  You could ask a local JVM for an object and get that much like a static reference or remotely another JVM could be asked for an object and you would get an object reference to cast.

Cannot get it working.  Can you guys help?  Main issue is the thread exiting before the readLine() method is finished exiting.  The call to readLine() simply exits the debugger session as if there is no more execution to trace!?!?

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package apml.system.bodi.remote;

/**
*
* @author Max Rupplin
*/

class Listenerthread extends Thread
{
public volatile Connection connection;

public Boolean running = true;

//public Basicserver server;

public volatile Inputlistenerthread inputlistenerthrread;

public volatile Outputlistenerthread outputlistenerthread;

public Listenerthread(Connection connection)
{
    this.connection = connection;

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    this.setName("Listenerthread");

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    this.inputlistenerthrread = new Inputlistenerthread(this);

    this.inputlistenerthrread.start();        

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    this.outputlistenerthread = new Outputlistenerthread(this);                

    this.outputlistenerthread.start();
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println(">   Server main thread started...");

    while(running)            
    {
        System.err.println("Listner thread now looping...");

        try
        {
            synchronized(this.inputlistenerthrread.lock)
            {
                if(this.inputlistenerthrread.hasreadready)
                {                    
                    this.inputlistenerthrread.checkinputqueue();                        

                    this.connection.isdonereading = true;
                }
            }

            synchronized(this.outputlistenerthread.lock)
            {
                if(this.outputlistenerthread.haswriteready)
                {
                    this.outputlistenerthread.checkoutputqueue();

                    this.connection.isdonewriting = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie)
            {
                running = false;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {                    
                e.printStackTrace();                                        
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Basicserver listener thread exiting...");
}       
}
```

/*----*/

```
package apml.system.bodi.remote;

/**
*
* @author Max Rupplin
 */
class Inputlistenerthread extends Thread  
{
public Boolean hasreadready = false;

public Boolean isnotchecking = true;

public Boolean running = true;

public volatile Listenerthread parent;

public volatile Object lock = new Object();

public Inputlistenerthread(Listenerthread parent)
{
    this.parent = parent;

    this.setName("Inputlistenerthread");                
}

public Boolean checkinputqueue()
{                
    synchronized(this.lock)
    {       
        StringBuffer inputbuffer = new StringBuffer();

        try
        {     
            //this.lock.wait();                           

            String line = null;                                

            while( (line = this.parent.connection.reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                inputbuffer.append(line);

                this.parent.connection.isdonereading = false;
            }

            if(inputbuffer.toString().length()>0) 
            {
                this.parent.connection.inqueue.append(inputbuffer);

                this.parent.connection.server.inputqueue.add(this.parent.connection);                                    

                this.parent.connection.hasreadready = true;

                this.parent.connection.isdonereading = true;    
            }                                   
        }
        catch(Error e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            inputbuffer = null;

            //this.lock.notifyAll();
        }           

        return true;            
    }
}  

@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println(">   Inputlistenerthread started...");

    try
    {
        while(running)
        {                
            try
            {
                //if(this.parent.server.reader.lines().count()>0 || true)
                if(true)
                {
                    this.hasreadready = true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(250);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This that you commented the `lock.wait()` line, does it not mean that the read could be null, and hence exit?

Comment: It seems, while in debug mode, to skip over the if(inputbuffer.toString().length()>0) line so I've assumed this is just not executing correctly the thread's execution.

Comment: That is the line that waits for there to be something in the queue to process. Otherwise the queue is empty and there is nothing to do so it exits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into a debugger, but the lines which you show commented out

```
//this.lock.wait();
```

are crucial to holding the thread running until there is something to process. Otherwise there is nothing to do (queue is empty) and the thread indeed exits immediately.